# Apollo client does not return empty query result

Tags: angular, observable, apollo-client

how do I force watchQuery valueChanges to return an empty result?
When I subscribe to it, it never returns if the query result is empty but I need to check the server DB for data existence. How to get null result response?

definition in dataservice (ds)

```
watchQry(qry: DocumentNode, vars?: R): Observable<ApolloQueryResult<Query>> {
    return this.apollo.watchQuery<Query>({ query: qry, variables: vars}).valueChanges;
  }
```

usage

```
this.ds.watchQry(query{sqlsToDo(sql_id:3){sql_id sql_text}})
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.sql = result.data && result.data.sqlsToDo;
        this.loading = result.loading;
        this.error = result.errors;
})
```

Playground works
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg72H.png

This does not help

```
return this.apollo.watchQuery<Query>({ query: qry, variables: vars, fetchPolicy: 'network-only'}).
      valueChanges;
```